# postgres 9.1 "IN6ADDR_ANY" is not exported by the Socket module

Tags: postgresql, installation

I searched but didn't find the answer why I got error on installation:

```
$ sudo aptitude install postgresql-9.1 postgresql-contrib-9.1 python-pygresql libpq-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initialising package states... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libossp-uuid16{a} postgresql-9.1 postgresql-common{a} postgresql-contrib-9.1 python-pygresql 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B/7,463kB of archives. After unpacking 21.2MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Writing extended state information... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package libossp-uuid16.
(Reading database ... 414497 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libossp-uuid16 (from .../libossp-uuid16_1.6.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package postgresql-common.
Unpacking postgresql-common (from .../postgresql-common_133~lucid_all.deb) ...
Adding `diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Selecting previously deselected package postgresql-9.1.
Unpacking postgresql-9.1 (from .../postgresql-9.1_9.1.4-1~lucid4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package postgresql-contrib-9.1.
Unpacking postgresql-contrib-9.1 (from .../postgresql-contrib-9.1_9.1.4-1~lucid4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package python-pygresql.
Unpacking python-pygresql (from .../python-pygresql_1%3a4.0-2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libossp-uuid16 (1.6.2-1ubuntu1) ...

Setting up postgresql-common (133~lucid) ...
"IN6ADDR_ANY" is not exported by the Socket module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm line 19
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/postgresql-common/run-upgrade-scripts line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/postgresql-common/run-upgrade-scripts line 18.
"IN6ADDR_ANY" is not exported by the Socket module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm line 19
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_checksystem line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_checksystem line 20.

Setting up postgresql-9.1 (9.1.4-1~lucid4) ...
**"IN6ADDR_ANY" is not exported by the Socket module
Can't continue after import errors at /usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm line 19
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm line 19.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/bin/pg_createcluster line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/pg_createcluster line 19.
Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with

  pg_createcluster 9.1 main --start

or a similar command (see 'man pg_createcluster').**
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.1/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode.

Setting up postgresql-contrib-9.1 (9.1.4-1~lucid4) ...

Setting up python-pygresql (1:4.0-2) ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Reading package lists... Done             
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initialising package states... Done
Writing extended state information... Done
```

I don't konw what's IN6ADDR_ANY and how set it to be exported by the Socket module.
I tried to install it on ubuntu 10.04 after sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Socket module was not updated, and the old version of Socket does not export IN6ADDR_ANY.  (see /usr/lib/perl/5.12.4/Socket.pm).  The version on my machine was 1.87_01, and that version does not export IN6ADDR_ANY.  The newest version is 2.002.

The problem was probably that someone forgot to enter Socket 2.002 as a dependency when they packaged the new postgresql-9.1 dpkg.

The fix is to update the Socket module:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsocket-perl
```

In case that doesn't work for you, try upgrading Socket via cpan:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cpan
$ sudo cpan Socket
```

Edit:

In the case where Socket won't install via the commands above and is bombing out with the message "BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Makefile.PL line 6", run:

```
$ sudo cpan ExtUtils::Constant
```

This will get you ExtUtils::Constant v0.23 which is necessary for updating Socket. You should then be able to run:

```
$ sudo cpan Socket
```

without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used other ppa and it worked:

ppa:flexiondotorg/postgres

To remove old one I used ppa-purge this way:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/53004738/ppa-purge_0%2Bbzr46.1~lucid1_all.deb &&
sudo dpkg -i ppa-purge_0+bzr46.1~lucid1_all.deb
sudo ppa-purge ppa:pitti/postgresql
```

Adding new ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/postgres
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the problem, I downgraded postgresql-client-common and postgresql-common back to the previous "130~lucid" versions.

Luckily, the packages were in my apt archive, located at /var/cache/apt/archives on my machine (running Ubuntu 10.10).

Simply installed them using dpkg

```
sudo dpkg -i postgresql-client-common_130~lucid_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i postgresql-common_130~lucid_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of funny that this just happened someone else on the same day it happened to me when I upgraded from postgres 8.4 to 9.1.
I had exactly the same problem and found the solution right here and just at the right time!

I # the rows 19 and 684 to 687 in /usr/share/postgresql-common/PgCommon.pm like someone (Billy Monk) wrote yesterday (and obviously changed or deleted his post now).

And it worked.

I will try the solution with updating the socket now.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me ( on Ubuntu 10.04LTS ):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libcpan-mini-perl
$ sudo cpan ExtUtils::Constant
$ sudo cpan Socket
```